# Incredibly obvious answer isn't obvious?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Somebody asked me why this was wrong, and I can't think of an answer.

It's basically asking you to create an expression for a number divided by 3.

So would this not be n/3? If you look in the picture, the answer is marked wrong.

[image]

Is this a glitch on the webpage or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Glitch on the webpage would be my guess.

Comment: This is definetely a glitch on the web site - your answer is most definetely correct. :)

Answer (score 5):

"A number divided by $3$" is indeed $n\div 3$.

(Alternatively the same is represented by $\dfrac n3$, but since $\dfrac n3$ isn't in the list of options go with the also-correct $n\div 3$.)

Comment: It’s the last of the six options.